# Поиск/фильтр среди Item

Tags: android, recyclerview, search

Как правильно реализовать, фильтр и поиск , у меня есть список отелей 
Название и количества звезд .
Нужно сделать сортировку по звездам и поиск по названию ... Как это реализовать более правильно и чисто.

Сразу скажу , я новичок в этом деле и желательно все с пояснениями , что и за что отвечает , чтобы я мог хоть немного понять структуру и приложить в других местах .

Заранее спасибо , если нужен какой-то фрагмент кода , пишите все отправим .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример поиска по полю. Это используете в активити(фрагмент) где лежит recyclerview

```
 sv= (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.mSearch);

        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                //FILTER AS YOU TYPE
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

В адаптере добавляю переменную      `CustomFilter filter`;
и метод

```
//RETURN FILTER OBJ
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(filter==null)
    {
        filter = new CustomFilter(mHistory,this);
    }
    return filter;
}
```

И сам класс в котором фильтрую данные. Для меня это по классу

`History`  по полю language, через метод `getLanguage()`

```
 public class CustomFilter extends Filter {
        Adapter adapter;
        ArrayList<History> filterList;
        public CustomFilter(ArrayList<History> filterList,Adapter adapter)
        {
            this.adapter=adapter;
            this.filterList=filterList;
        }
        //FILTERING OCURS
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
            //CHECK CONSTRAINT VALIDITY
            if(constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
            {
                //CHANGE TO UPPER
                constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                //STORE OUR FILTERED PLAYERS
                ArrayList<History> filteredPlayers=new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i=0;i<filterList.size();i++)
                {
                    //CHECK
                    if(filterList.get(i).getLanguage().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                    {
                        //ADD HISTORY TO FILTERED PLAYERS
                        filteredPlayers.add(filterList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                results.count=filteredPlayers.size();
                results.values=filteredPlayers;
            }else
            {
                results.count=filterList.size();
                results.values=filterList;
            }
            return results;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            adapter.mHistory= (ArrayList<History>) results.values;
            //REFRESH
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }



        public ArrayList<History> getFilterList()
        {
            return filterList;
        }
    }
```

Вот результат как работает у меня.Может вам пригодится

[image: Исходное]

[image: Пример 1][image: Пример 2]